# Always having to sign into Apple Game Center in simulator in iOS7?

Tags: ios7, game-center, xcode5

I'm working on a game which requires the user to have an Apple Game Center account. Prior to XCode 5/iOS7 I would run the game in the simulator, if the player wasn't signed into GC it would show the dialogue, if they were they got a game center signed in msg, and that was that, didn't have to sign into GC again.

I upgraded to XCode5/iOS7 last night, and now each time I run a simulator for the first time, or when I switch to another simulator, it asks to be signed into GC again, any ideas why this is?

Comment: This is annoying the hell out of me too.

Comment: If you switch to another simulator, then it is effectively a different device (you will notice that if you are normally working on multiple apps, and then start using a new simulator, the new simulator won't have any of your old apps - i.e. the apps you compiled.). The data changes you make to one simulator are not "saved" or "cloned" to another simulator...